# Magento won't send subscription confirmation email

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter

As in subject, My Magento won't send subscription confirmation `email`.
Did some research, found one interesting thing - add extra line into **app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php**

```
$this->sendConfirmationSuccessEmail();
```

but it still won't send confirmation message.

Comment: did you checked the magento log and also apache log?

Comment: I tried to check system.log in Magento var but the size is ..... enormous :) but not checked apache log yet, will do. Thank you

Comment: try to rename the system.log file and then send conformation email again.

Comment: You could also just tail the system log, in the command line:

`tail -100 path/to/your/log/file.log` will echo the last 100 lines of your log file